# How to convert difference between two times into hours only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I found the answer to this, but unfortunately it's using Java.  I have two times, formatted as HHmm (no colons).  I need to figure out how many 15 minute time segments are in the difference.  For example, I have a start time of 1000 and an end time of 1130 (military time).

When I subtract the two dates, I get 130, which is meaningless for computations.

Is there an existing method that will do this for me?  (I have spent the last 6 hours trying SO and Google, but found nothing).

**UPDATE**:  I would appreciate it if whoever downvoted me please reverse it.  The question is *very* pertinent and others will find it useful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -[NSCalendar components:fromDate:toDate:options], like this:

```
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalenderUnitMinute fromDate:startDate toDate:endDate options:0];
NSInteger numberOfMinutes = [components minute];
```

Once you have the number of minutes, it should just be a matter of dividing by 15 to get the number of 15 minute chunks.

Answer (score 3):

Parse each time and convert to minutes. So 1000 becomes 10 hours 0 minutes for a total of 600 minutes. 1130 becomes 11 hours 30 minutes for a total of 690 minutes. Subtract the two values for a difference of 90 minutes. Now divide by 15 to get 6.

The following assumes all times are 4 digit military times:

```
NSString *startTime = @"1000";
NSString *endTime = @"1130";
int startMinues = [[startTime substringToIndex:2] intValue] * 60 + [[startTime substringFromIndex:2] intValue];
int endMinues = [[endTime substringToIndex:2] intValue] * 60 + [[endTime substringFromIndex:2] intValue];
int minutes = endMinutes - startMinutes;
int units = minutes / 15;
```

This gives whole units of your 15 minute blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSDateComponents:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit
                                       fromDate:dateA
                                         toDate:dateB
                                        options:0];
int increments = components.hour*4 + components.minute/15;
```

Answer (score 0):

Format is rather simple:

```
int HHmm = [date intValue];
int HH = HHmm / 100;
int mm = HHmm % 100;
```

Diff, for two parsed dates:

```
int diff = ((HH2 * 60 + mm2) - (HH1 * 60 + mm1)) / 15;
```